# InvalidOperationException when calling SaveChanges in .NET Entity framework with Oracle ODP.NET

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, odp.net

I have a code which deletes some entities from database and then re-insert updated rows. Scheme is following:

```
 db.BeginTransaction();
 try
 {
    //Delete some rows
    db.SaveChanges();
    //Add updated rows
    db.SaveChanges();
    db.Commit()
 }
 catch
 {
    db.Rollback();
    throw;
 }
```

In some cases, but not in general I have following error just after the second SaveChanges:

> The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error
>   occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be
>   in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: AcceptChanges
>   cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another
>   object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are
>   unique before calling AcceptChanges.

Database is Oracle, I use ODP.NET Oracle provider to make it work with Entity Framework. Updated table uses composite primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To cut a long story short - it's duplicated composite primary key values in data.**

In general the error indicates that some kind of inconsistency appears in object context or between context and database. It's often caused by modifying some data in the meantime (by something else than EF), for instance by stored procedure, so the context becomes outdated.

However in this case problem is somewhere else. Namely in a composite key. It's quite easy to overlook it in the data, but if we have primary key which is made of three, four, five values and somewhere in the list of rows to be updated the key is duplicated Entity Framework will throw that exception.

Comment: So, did you find your problem?

Comment: Yes. It's Q&A style, but I just can't accept my answer immediately.